# How to compute in R eigenvalues and respective multiplicities of an adjacency matrix?

Tags: r, network-programming, linear-algebra

I have a symmetric adjacency matrix with binary values (0, 1) in R. Let's say:

```
library(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(10, 10, type="gnm", directed = FALSE, loops = TRUE)
m <- get.adjacency(g)
```

I need to do spectrum analysis of this graph, by producing a list of sublists of eigenvalues with their respective multiplicities. I am aware of functions like `eigen(m)`. This previous question used it, but did not explain any automatic way for counting multiplicities:

[number of distinct eigenvectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433981/number-of-distinct-eigenvectors-in-r)

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: Currently, I am using igraph package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the multiplicity of an eigenvalue is *n*, it appears *n* times in `eigen(m)$values`.